# What's "teststackoverflow.com" and how does it affect me?

Tags: support

I was just reading one of the other questions here on meta, when I noticed that I had a NoScript notification indicating that there was some blocked content on the page. This is pretty unusual for SO, so I took at look at it and this is what I saw:

[image: Image showing the NoScript dialog with a new entry for teststackoverflow]

What is this (new?) teststackoverflow, and what effects will allowing it/leaving it blocked have on the site?

When I navigated away from the question I was reading this no longer popped up (I dismissed the dialog without doing anything with it), so it doesn't appear to be present on every page.

Comment: Related: [Cookies and JavaScript for teststackoverflow.com — legitimate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221591/cookies-and-javascript-for-teststackoverflow-com-legitimate)

Comment: I am so happy that the answer has nothing to do with overflowing testicles. That was my initial fear upon seeing the domain name.

Comment: Reporting minor typo on [the page](http://teststackoverflow.com/): "*The intent is to keep **ay** eye on performance and evaluate infrastructure changes and the impact they have.*".

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A description is present at http://teststackoverflow.com/ itself.

Here is a part of it that seemed interesting to me:

> This domain helps us evaluate changes in DNS, geolocation, SSL termination, load balancing, and routing so that we can make all Stack Exchange sites faster all over the world. You may have arrived here from looking at our iframe, welcome! We are not adding this extra hit to every request, but less than 1% of the requests to our network.

It looks like you may block it without any consequences (except for Stack Exchange having the tiniest bit less diagnostic information).

Comment: I was hesitant to try going there directly as I could find no mention of it here on meta - so I wasn't sure if it was a legitimate part of the stack exchange network. Possibly call me paranoid... That page is pretty self explanatory, and even shows a full dump of what was sent to the SE servers. Thanks!

Comment: _"The intent is to keep ay eye on performance"_ ow my eyes. Also, comma abuse in a few places.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *Most our pages render in less than 100ms*

Comment: @eggy Sadly, I spent a while fretting about the lack of a (thin)space in `100ms` before noticing the lack of "of".

Comment: @michaelb958: Pardon?

Comment: The [`whois` record](http://who.is/whois/teststackoverflow.com) for this domain pretty clearly identifies it as a Stack site.

Comment: @PeterMortensen What michaelb958 meant, is that in scientific articles you have a (thin)space e.g. LaTex: \, between a value and its unit. Yet the "bigger" error in eggy's comment is the lack of "of" as the second word: "Most of our...". Yet in my opinion these are comments and not nesseccary from native speakers (take me for example) so minor "errors" should be ignored.

Comment: _"...except for Stack Exchange having the tiniest bit less diagnostic information"_ Unless lots of people read your answer!

Comment: Throwback to the old favicon.  I used to miss it, after seeing it now the new one is much better.

Comment: "Stack Exchange having the tiniest bit less diagnostic information" isn't entirely correct.  It will be diagnosed that `teststackoverflow.com` wasn't reachable from your location, which may seriously defeat the purpose.

Comment: My ResponseEnd time took `-2ms`. Impressive!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You must have hit some code that [Jon Skeet wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/). That would explain the timing.