# What's dev.stackoverflow.com about?

Tags: support, moderator-abilities, dev.so

I just realized that there is a Stack Overflow "development and testing" site (http://dev.stackoverflow.com/) that says that you must receive an invitation e-mail in order to join. I have a couple questions about it:

1. Who has access to it? Developers only? All SE employees? *Moderators?* Rather than being paid employees of Stack Exchange, moderators seem to me like *volunteer* employees of Stack Exchange, so thus they should have access to it.
2. Can normal users get an invite?  And, if so, how?

Comment: Elected moderators are indeed volunteers, but not employees of SE.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267143/whats-teststackoverflow-com-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is our development server - where our build server pushes stuff to after commits (as part of a CI process). It is our first place to smoke-out and test our fixes/features/new bugs (after our own dev machines).

1. Stack Exchange developers and employees. Who have an invite. No moderators.
2. No.

Comment: Aww… I want an invite.

Comment: So do all moderators...I guess.

Comment: We have several open positions for [developers](http://stackexchange.com/work-here)...

Comment: Most moderators don't want to be working in *two* full-time jobs at the same time, right?

Comment: It showed up in Bing search results when I was searching there. Is it not supposed to show up there?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - what were you searching for?

Comment: @Oded I don't remember the exact search query, but searching for ["stack overflow development"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=stack%20overflow%20development&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=stack%20overflow%20development&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=348baa61643e4eab9733d68db2cbd506) causes it to show up as the fourth search result.

Comment: Ah. That's OK, so long as it is just the login page coming up and not actual question/answer links (that are not accessible). @damryfbfnetsi

Comment: Speaking of which, are you guys planning on creating a "test site" for users (with the necessary combined SE rep) for them to be able to test out the capabilities of mods or any rep level users? This will greatly help us in that we can answer questions of low-rep users without having to recall how we were at the time or create sockpuppets. In addition, this will also help prospective mods test out the mod features without having to become an actual moderator or cause disruptions on real sites. Wikipedia has the test wiki for that purpose: https://www.thetestwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: I am not aware of any such plans. You could make a [meta-tag:feature-request], @damryfbfnetsi

Comment: Why is it on a public IP, and not resolved to an IP in your private network?

Comment: @self many devs are remote.

Comment: Facebook's `dev.t.facebook` resolves to IP address `10.82.0.145`

Comment: @self we are not facebook

Comment: The fact that your development domain is resolved to a public IP, but is not available to the public correlates perfectly with the fact that your primary technology stack is provided by proprietary software provided by Microsoft.

Comment: @self wow. You sound like you really know your stuff.